# DataTables warning: table id=table - Ajax error

Tags: laravel, datatables

La verdad  no entiendo por que se da este  erro  y  si me cargan los datos
alguien q me pueda explicar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque el ajax no responde con un código de respuesta 2xx (éxito). Lo idea es depurar la url del ajax a ver cuál puede ser el fallo... De todas maneras, si estás seguro que la tabla está correcta y lo que quieres hacer en este punto es simplemente ocultar ese mensaje, lo puedes hacer así:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
```

Un saludo.